# What is terminal key code for Ctrl+Backspace

Tags: shell, terminal

I'm trying to find <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> terminal keycode to make it delete whole words in shell.

While it is explained how to get those codes for <kbd>arrows</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd> and such keys with `cat` or `od` commands:

- [Fix key settings (Home/End/Insert/Delete) in .zshrc when running Zsh in Terminator Terminal Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638012/fix-key-settings-home-end-insert-delete-in-zshrc-when-running-zsh-in-terminat)
- [what is terminal escape sequence for ctrl + arrow (left, right,...) in TERM=linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767702/what-is-terminal-escape-sequence-for-ctrl-arrow-left-right-in-term-linu)

or codes given directly here: https://code.google.com/p/mintty/wiki/Keycodes (^_ doesn't work for me)
I can't find a way to get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backpace</kbd> code.

Any clues? Thanks.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Linux CentOS 7, using putty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cursor- and home/end (editing-keypad) keys are different from the backspace key.  Those always send some type of escape sequence.  The backspace key does not.  It sends a single control character, which makes it a *control sequence*, rather than an *escape sequence*.  This distinction is used in the [xterm manual](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h2-CONTROL-SEQUENCES-AND-KEYBOARD).

Control/backspace (like any case where a control-modifier is applied to a *control* character) is a feature that *may* be provided by a terminal, but has no general meaning (much less a standard meaning).  rxvt (during the 1990s) used this combination to switch between ASCII `BS` (`^H` or 8) and `DEL` (`^?`, or 127).  xterm incorporated that in 1998 ([patch #83](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_83)) for the same purpose.  By the way, as a VT220 emulator, xterm refers to this as the "backarrow key" (VT200s had that, not a backspace key).

PuTTY does not appear to provide that feature; its behavior for control/backspace is the same as without the control-modifier.